# Setting up apache guacamole with custom font for ssh

Tags: docker, fonts, guacamole

I am trying to set up a powerline modded font for SSH connection using apache guacamole docker container.

The container is set up and working and without setting a font name everything works well.

Once I enter a [font name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG9Nm.png) I get weird spacing and use of the wrong font, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAV7P.png)

Here is how my container is set:

```
docker run --name=guacamole -d \
--network exposed-containers \
--restart=unless-stopped \
-e GUACD_HOSTNAME=guacd \
-e MYSQL_HOSTNAME=mariadb \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole \
-e MYSQL_USER=guacamole \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=redacted \
-v /usr/share/fonts/Hack-Regular.ttf:/usr/share/fonts/Hack-Regular.ttf \
-v /usr/share/fonts/dejavu.ttf:/usr/share/fonts/dejavu.ttf \
-v /usr/share/fonts/notomono.ttf:/usr/share/fonts/notomono.ttf \
-p 9011:8080 guacamole/guacamole
```

Inside the container the fonts are detected and are working fine:

```
root@49d47e4258d3:/opt/guacamole# fc-list
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: DejaVu Sans:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/dejavu.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/Hack-Regular.ttf: Hack:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Sans:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/notomono.ttf: Noto Mono for Powerline:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Book
root@49d47e4258d3:/opt/guacamole#
```

The font I am trying to use is monospace as is needed for guacamole and I have used that font before on linux and windows so I know it works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a monospace font like Droid Sans Mono

for Centos:

```
yum install google-droid-sans-mono-fonts
```

it will download a font named "DroidSansMono.ttf"

now edit `user-mapping.xml` under /etc/guacamole

My connection parameters are like this

```
 <connection name="localhost">
            <protocol>ssh</protocol>
            <param name="hostname">ServerName</param>
            <param name="port">22</param>
            <param name="password">PassWord</param>
            <param name="font-name">DroidSansMono</param>
            <param name="font-size">10</param>
   </connection>
```

Note the font name and the "font-name" parameter are same except ttf  extension.
I can see the fonts properly now.[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting up font config for that font?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the fonts in the `guacd` container fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ssh connection is processed by the `guacd` container. So, instead of adding fonts in `guacamole`, you need to add them into `guacd`.